# Vuetify 3 components not working in chrome - Uncaught TypeError: globalStack.at is not a function

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, typeerror

I am getting this error running a Vue JS project with vuetify 3 plugin project created from scratch. I am specifically using v-dialog, but it's getting console errors in chrome for other components as well.

`

```
Uncaught TypeError: globalStack.at is not a function
    at stack.ts:55
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:157)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166)
    at ReactiveEffect.getter [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1732)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:187)
    at doWatch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1847)
    at watchEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1652)
    at useStack (stack.ts:54)
    at Object.setup [as _setup] (VOverlay.tsx:149)
    at setup (defineComponent.tsx:77)`
```

```
My package.json looks like below-
```

``

```
{
  "name": "vuetify-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/types": "^7.20.5",
    "@mdi/font": "7.0.96",
    "esbuild": "^0.16.10",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.2.38",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "@types/webfontloader": "^1.6.35",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.9",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.9"
  }
}``
```

```
I have tried various conditions like upgrading nodejs version, disabling vite and enabling vue-cli but the issue didn't resolve
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade your browser - at() function has been added fairly recently. If you get latest Chrome it works just fine. If you are using node, upgrade your node to 16.6 or later

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with you it's about dependency problem i guess.
please try this

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu
ncu -u
```

and run your project again